# How to set a field which can do both structured query and full text query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I am ES newbie. I do not want to store the same data into tow column, one column as full text query, another column as structured query or wildcard query. I do not known whether i can use one column data to do the different query?

Comment: You can index your data more than once using different analyzers, one adapted to full text query (default one) and one for wildcard, see how: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: @Pandawan The multi-fields whether will generate duplicate index data

Comment: Not duplicate, try an index with this mapping and two indexes, one for wildcards and one for full text query, you will see that it is not the same size (raw data is not duplicated with multiple fields, both field reference the same position where raw data is stored)